# Need to SUM duplicate values and insert them in another worksheet based on the value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm working in Excel 2010, trying to create a manual cross-referencing  inventory stock. I have two worksheets:

1. The "intakes" that have two columns that I'm using: "Product" and "quantity". Since I have purchases from many months I have repeated products with different quantities.
2. The "stock" worksheet that have the "product" column, "initial stock" and "intakes". The product column have unique values from the data base that have the same names as the ones from "intakes".

What I want to do is create a function that Sums all the quantities from intakes based on the duplicates from the products column and place that sum in the "intakes column from the stock worksheet based on the product name.

Also, since the "intakes" worksheet will expand every month I need a formula that's not static.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the schema from both worksheets:

"Intakes sheet"

| PRODUCT | QUANTITY |
| --- | --- |
| BACTRIM FORTE // comp.x 10 // Siegfried 0 | 2 |
| LEVOTIROXINA GSK // 100 mcg comp.x 50 // GlaxoSmithKline0 | 1 |
| DELTISONA B // 4 mg comp.x 20 // Elea 0 | 1 |
| DENTI. COLGATE TOTAL 12 CLEAN MINT X90G // COLGATE TOTAL 12 CLEAN M // Colgate | 5 |
| VALCOTE // 125 mg comp.x 50 // Abbott EPD 0 | 2 |
| NOZINAN // 25 mg comp.x 30 // Sanofi-Aventis 0 | 1 |

"Stock Sheet"

| PRODUCT | INITIAL | INTAKES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DENTI. COLGATE TOTAL 12 CLEAN MINT X90G // COLGATE TOTAL 12 CLEAN M // Colgate | 0 | 0 |
| 102 PLUS // comp.x 60 // Laboratorio Gra0 | 0 | 0 |
| 102 PLUS // comp.x 90 // Laboratorio Gra0 | 0 | 0 |
| 102 SPORT BCAA // sob.x 30 // Laboratorio Gra0 | 0 | 1 |
| ACCU-CHEK GUIDE // tiras reactivas x 50 // Roche Diabetes 0 | 0 | 49 |
| ACCU-CHEK PERFORMA 25 // tiras reactivas x 25 // Roche Diabetes 0 | 0 | 0 |
| ACCU-CHEK PERFORMA 50 // tiras reactivas x 50 // Roche Diabetes 0 | 0 | 30 |

I tried using SUMIF but for some reason I only get the correct numbers of some products. Maybe I should do a combination of SUM and VLOOKUP but I'm not entirely sure on how to do it. This is the formula I used:

```
=SUMIF(intakes!D:D;"="&A:A;intakes!E:E)
```

I did a VLOOKUP `[=VLOOKUP($A2;intakes!D:E;2;0)]` to see if it was retrieving the values properly but I'm getting an #NA error for all the products that are 0 in the "intakes" column.

Edit:Thanks for the clarification P.B. I added the formatting and the formula I used.

Comment: So post some sample data (not images) using https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables Also share the expected outcome with this sample data and your formula you used that didn't give you the expected results.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's QUITE difficult to decipher what you're looking for, but since you're new I'm going to give it a shot.

- First, I'm assuming that you take your Intakes and Stock Sheet data
  and make them tables (Select them in their entirety and do insert >
  table).
- Second, name them appropriately (Click on the table, click Design
  in the ribbon, then change Table Name).
- Finally, in your Intake column on the Stock Sheet, you can paste this
  formula:

  `=SUMIF(Intakes[PRODUCT],[@PRODUCT],Intakes[QUANTITY])`

Now, this is a lot of assumptions, so ask questions as needed to find a solution that works for you.